# Populate a cell with data from a sub when excel template opens

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

Lets say I've created a macro-enabled excel template. In this template I create a sub to obtain a string value and assign it to a variable, say `var_1` in the sub. I save the template and close excel.
Now the next time I start excel and load the template, I want the vlaue in `var_1` to be populated in a particular cell, say `A1`.
The cell should get populated as soon as the template finishes loading. How do I do it?

**EDIT:** The value of `var_1` might change everytime the workbook (template) opens.

Thank you.

Comment: Will the value of var_1 change each time the workbook is opened? Or do you want to preserve the value previously entered and saved and enter that in A1?

Comment: @datatoo Yes the value might change at times. I mean you can't tell when it will change. So basically we have to assume it changes each time the workbook (template) opens.

Answer (score 0):

*Somanna, you can try this VBA code will take care how to pass value to variable and write into Cell.*

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim InCell As Integer

    For InCell = 1 To 5 Step 1
        Cells(InCell, 1).Value = _
            InputBox("Enter the value", "New Value,,,")
    Next InCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- *Open the Template File*, press    **Alt+F11** to open VB editor.
- On top left find **Project Explorer**,    Click on **This Workbook** Icon.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this code, back to     Worksheet.
- **Close** the Workbook & **Open** it    again,this code will pop up **Inputbox.**
- Write the Value you want to populated 
  into Cells.

**N.B.**

- Since it's `Workbook Open event` so every time you open the Template, Excel will read the Code to get different value for variable to write into Cell.
- For Loop `1 To 5 Step 1` determines that `Input Box` appears `5` times (it is editable).

*Suppose is, `1 To 5 Step 2` then code will ask only for 3 values, since it writes assigned value after skipping one blank Row (in Row 1, 3 & 5).*

- `InCell, 1`, here `1` is for `Column 1`, means `A` ,which is editable. (for `Col B` it should `2`).

Comment: It's not working, when I open the template the cell doesn't populate

Comment: @Somanna,, where you have entered this code,,, I think with Workbook,, now check the post, there I've written the procedure !